# ExecJS::RuntimeError in Tests#index on ruby on rails with mongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

Error Message:

> ExecJS::RuntimeError in Tests#index Showing
>   D:/dropWithCoffee/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6
>   raised:
>   SyntaxError: [stdin]:1:1: unexpected //

I tried the following solutions from Internet:

> First Solution:

Changed the File at:

> Ruby2.1.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\gems\execjs-2.6.0\lib\execjs\runtimes.rb

From:

```
JScript = ExternalRuntime.new(
      name:        "JScript",
      command:     "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo //U",
      runner_path: ExecJS.root + "/support/jscript_runner.js",
      encoding:    ''UTF-16LE'' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE
    )
```

To:

```
JScript = ExternalRuntime.new(
      name:        "JScript",
      command:     "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo",
      runner_path: ExecJS.root + "/support/jscript_runner.js",
      encoding:    'UTF-8' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE
    )
```

Nothing Changed:

> Second Solution:

Uncommented the following Line in gem file:
`gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby`
And run `bundle`.
Error Still there.

> Third Solution:

Changed the coffee gem from 1.9.0 to 1.8.0 version.
coffee gem in my gem file is
`gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'`
And run the `bundle update` command.
No Change.

> Fourth Solution:

Removed the   `//= require_tree .`
line from `application.js`.It solved the problem but coffeescript is not loading on my browser.
Below is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
#gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'execjs'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 5'
gem 'bson_ext'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Rails version:4.2.4.
Ruby version:2.1.5p273.
OS: windows 7.
No Solution above worked.

This is my development log during this error:

```
    Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-11-03 12:14:37 +0530
Processing by TestsController#index as HTML
  Rendered tests/index.html.erb within layouts/application (79599.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 84949ms

ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: [stdin]:1:1: unexpected //):
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>DropWithCoffee</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
    9: <body>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1027629002_58458144'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (29.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (122.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (20.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (495.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (3.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (267.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (4.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (672.0ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of small Syntax error.I found in the Log the error is because of `//` in my file.It is because of the comments.
In `.js`.we comment as `//`.but,where as in coffee script we comment it as `#`.i changed the `.js` file to `.js.coffee`.But not the comment line.This caused the error.I am posting this,if this may help others who come across the same problem.